# How does HDCP detection work?

Tags: drm, video

What is the mechanism used by websites like HBO GO to detect [HDCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-bandwidth_Digital_Content_Protection) bypassing/violation? How foolproof is this mechanism, as the logic lies on the client side?

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on the device where the app is running (smartphone/tablet, set-top-box, smart TV...) but typically the detection happens in code running in a CPU mode (and using reserved memory) that cannot be accessed by regular apps. The most typical implementation is by means of a [Trusted Execution Environment (TEE)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_execution_environment).

Answer (score 1):

Before transmitting High Definition content, the transmitter initiates authentication process with receiver and exchanges the  KSV. Basically it is having three level of authentication. 1. Authentication between transmitter & receiver. 2, if receiver is repeater, additional authentication, 3 during data transfer every blanking interval.